# can someone help me to know jdk version compatibility on org.reflections.Reflections jar

Tags: java, reflections

I m using Reflections.jar for the first time, so i like to know the following

- Is there any version compatibility for this jar(like above jdk6 (or) upto jdk8)
- While loading classes is there any order of loading(like alphabetical order (or) order of jar placed in classpath)

Comment: Classes are loaded on need base. For information how a class is found you might have a look here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html

Comment: Thanks for responding... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html In this author explained very generically, but my doubt is **Is there any specific kind of class loading in Reflections** , If yes what is that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about this https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections project then it find the classes in the order they appear in your classpath like the Java launcher would do. The way how classes are found and loaded is described here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html.

The first class file in the classpath order which matches the full class name is loaded. Find a small snippet below for demonstration.

assume following directories and files

```
lib/annotations-2.0.1.jar
lib/guava-15.0.jar
lib/javassist-3.18.2-GA.jar
lib/reflections-0.9.9.jar
src/DummyInterface.java
src/Main.java
src1/DummyClass1.java
src2/DummyClass1.java
```

**src/DummyInterface.java**

```
package sub.optimal;
public interface DummyInterface {}
```

**src/Main.java**

```
import org.reflections.Reflections;
import sub.optimal.DummyInterface;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections("sub.optimal");
        for (Class c : reflections.getSubTypesOf(DummyInterface.class)) {
            System.out.println("class: " + c.getCanonicalName());
            c.newInstance();
        }
   }
}
```

**src1/DummyClass1.java**

```
package sub.optimal;
public class DummyClass1 implements DummyInterface {
    static {
        System.out.println("touched DummyClass 1");
    }
}
```

**src2/DummyClass1.java**

```
package sub.optimal;
public class DummyClass1 implements DummyInterface {
    static {
        System.out.println("touched DummyClass 2");
    }
}
```

first compile the classes, for the demonstration we create the class files in different locations

```
javac -cp lib/* -d bin/ src/DummyInterface.java src/Main.java
javac -cp bin/:lib/* -d bin1/ src1/DummyClass1.java
javac -cp bin/:lib/* -d bin2/ src2/DummyClass1.java
```

executing `Main` with `bin1/` before `bin2/` in the class path will find and load the `DummyClass1` in `bin1/`

```
java -cp bin/:bin1/:bin2/:lib/* Main
```

output

```
class: sub.optimal.DummyClass1
touched DummyClass 1
```

executing `Main` with `bin2/` before `bin1/` in the class path will find and load the `DummyClass1` in `bin2/`

```
java -cp bin/:bin2/:bin1/:lib/* Main
```

output

```
class: sub.optimal.DummyClass1
touched DummyClass 2
```

Comment: Is there any way to change this behavior. For Example, I have jars say             `A.jar with classes Z.class,Y.class.... and B.jar - classes F.class,G.class`                **Z.class dependent with F.class**                                                                    i have set these jars in classpath has Z.jar;Y.jar; , If this is the case how the class will be loaded? and if want to load first Y.class and then G.class, is there any way to do this?  - Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @sera If `A.jar` (and no any other JAR file in the class path) don't contain a `F.class`, then the order of `A.jar` and `B.jar` doesn't matter. If `A.jar` and `B.jar` contain a `F.class` and you want the `F.class` to be loaded from `B.jar` then `B.jar` must appear before `A.jar` in the class path.

Answer (score 0):

1) According to https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections/blob/master/pom.xml, it is compiled with java 1.7, so it is compatible with java version >=1.7
2) http://javarevisited.blogspot.ru/2012/07/when-class-loading-initialization-java-example.html

Comment: http://javarevisited.blogspot.ru/2012/07/when-class-loading-initialization-java-example.html   In this author explained very generically, so i got doubt like, **is it suits for Refelections too? , is there any method used for loading classes in Reflections?** Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood your second question. As for how Reflections loads classes  - I don't know, you might check their docs or source code, since it is open source.